# What is the state of the art for GWAS in terms of the statistical algorithm for either Case/control and Quantitative traits?

Tags: statistics, gwas

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/410466/)*

I'm trying to understand what is the best algorithm for GWAS nowadays.
I know we have many tools available like Plink and Hail, but currently, what is the best algorithm if I won't use any them? Let's say, write down a script in R or Python from scratch. Which statistical algorithm should I use?
Is it Linear mixed models (LMMs)? I'm confused as we can have binary phenotypes (case/control) or quantitative phenotypes. LMM seems to address quantitative ones, but can it be used for case/control as well? 
Actually, what is the state of the art for both/each of them? Pair-reviewed papers as references will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: you're asking what the best algorithm is, assuming you don't want to use the well-tested and validated algorithms that other people are using?

Comment: It can be whatever anyone is using. I just want to know what is the algorithm behind the scene for binary or quantitative phenotypes.

Comment: This is not a good fit for a Bioinformatics Stack Exchange question, as the question is too broad and primarily opinion-based. I'd recommend that you ask something like this on [reddit](reddit.com/r/bioinformatics). The best questions on BSE deal with specific problems that people are having. If you think your question *is* specific, please edit it to make that more obvious.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. I'm not looking for opinions, but the algorithm that, mathematically, (through statistical tests) prooves to be the state-of-the-art. I've got the answer, check it out below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer to my question at https://www.biostars.org/p/410466/ by [chrchang522](https://www.biostars.org/u/9575/)

> "The main regression executed by Plink was introduced by EIGENSTRAT in ~2006; see https://www.nature.com/articles/ng1847 . This is actually straightforward to write in R/Python from scratch; the harder part is optimizing the implementation for large datasets.
>
> The Firth regression added to Plink 2.0 to improve handling of rare variants and imbalanced binary phenotypes was motivated by https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4049324/ .
>
> Mixed linear models provide better statistical power when you have lots of close relatives in your dataset, but are much trickier to solve; actually, this is still a significant research area. Two tools covering parts of the current state-of-the-art are SAIGE (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6119127/ ; handles imbalanced binary phenotypes, but relatively slow) and fastGWA (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-019-0530-8 ; great speed, but doesn't support dosage data yet and uses a misspecified model for binary phenotypes)."